# How to write htaccess file for this issue?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, cpanel

I have CPanel and the main Website is stored in Main-Site folder and this is my current .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !Main-Site/
RewriteRule (.*) /Main-Site/$1 [L]



RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]



ErrorDocument 206  /errors/206.html
ErrorDocument 301  /errors/301.html
ErrorDocument 302  /errors/302.html
ErrorDocument 400  /errors/400.html
ErrorDocument 401  /errors/401.html
ErrorDocument 403  /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404  /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 408  /errors/408.html
ErrorDocument 500  /errors/500.html
ErrorDocument 501  /errors/501.html
ErrorDocument 503  /errors/503.html
```

But this .htaccess file is affecting subdomains like `docs.example.com`

Like it goes to 404.html when I try to access subdomain
how to resolve this? I'm also forced to redirect https

Comment: “Affecting” what exactly, and how? You need to give us a _proper_ description of what goes wrong.

Comment: I just edited the question. Please check

Comment: Compare the patterns you used to check on the host name in the first and second block. Notice any significant difference between both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution for problem

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Main-Site/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Main-Site/$1  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ Main-Site/ [L]

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch


RewriteEngine On

# Apply these rules BEFORE rules in child .htaccess files
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect for all subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]



ErrorDocument 206  /errors/206.html
ErrorDocument 301  /errors/301.html
ErrorDocument 302  /errors/302.html
ErrorDocument 400  /errors/400.html
ErrorDocument 401  /errors/401.html
ErrorDocument 403  /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404  /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 408  /errors/408.html
ErrorDocument 500  /errors/500.html
ErrorDocument 501  /errors/501.html
ErrorDocument 503  /errors/503.html
```